# Error with compiling Nokogiri to install Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, osx-mavericks

I've been trying to install Rails on my computer today but I can't seem to figure it out. After using

```
gem install rails
```

I get a lot of errors I can't seem to decipher. They seem to be related to Nokogiri, but after 3-4 hours of seemingly random installations and "fixes" I am nowhere.

I tried using

```
gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.5 -- --use-system-libraries
```

and got

```
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/xlforloser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150103-18446-1ac5ew1.rb extconf.rb --use-system-libraries
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-      future... no
Building nokogiri using system libraries.
libxml2 version 2.6.21 or later is required!
```

If I only run `gem install rails`, I got

```
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.2... ERROR, review '/Users/xlforloser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.2/compile.log' to see what happened.
```

Please help!

Comment: it's says to check your `compile.log` for more details. I wish you could do that and post that here.

Comment: Add the output of `gem env` to your question, and format it for readability.

Answer (score 1):

You have two hints about the problem:

- `libxml2 version 2.6.21 or later is required!`
- `...review '/Users/xlforloser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.5/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.2/compile.log' to see what happened.`

To fix these:

- Read what is in compile.log and search for information about what it says.
- Read through the "Related" answers on the right-side of this page. Read them *ALL* before doing something. Too many times people try one thing, then another, then another, and end up making the problem worse because not everyone's situation applies to them.
- You can use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) to install a current version of libxml2.